# How do you get CPU ID or serial number using Hyperic Sigar?

Tags: java, uniqueidentifier, sigar, hyperic

Is there a method in the Sigar API that returns the CPU ID of the host running the JVM?

Comment: link might help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323364/using-sigar-api-to-get-jvm-cpu-usage

Comment: Hi @KamleshArya the link deals with process IDs and what I need to know is Processor ID.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, the closest you will get is the [`CpuInfo.getVendorId()`](http://www.hyperic.com/support/docs/sigar/org/hyperic/sigar/CpuInfo.html#getVendor%28%29) method.  That would give you the ID for the CPU type ... not a unique ID for the actual chip.