# Getting process CPU usage using Sigar library

Tags: java, jvm, cpu, cpu-usage, sigar

I've been trying to get a process CPU usage by using [Sigar library](https://support.hyperic.com/display/SIGAR/Home) but I always get values of 0 even when it should be higher.

I'm doing this on a timer every second:

```
Sigar sigar = new Sigar();
long pid = find.find("Exe.Name.ct=myprocess.exe");

ProcCpu cpu = sigar.getProcCpu(pid);
System.out.println(cpu.getPercent());
```

I've been taking a look at [this other related question and its accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323364/using-sigar-api-to-get-jvm-cpu-usage/19328057?noredirect=1#comment34062053_19328057) but it doesn't seem to work properly plus things like `TOTAL_TIME_UPDATE_LIMIT` are kind of a mystery. 
I also took a look at [this another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999392/how-to-get-cpu-ram-and-network-usage-of-a-java7-app) but it didn't provide to me anything new.

Has anyone tried to monitor the process CPU before with Sigar? 
What's the way to accomplish it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use it like this

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
        final Sigar sigar = new Sigar();
        while (true) {
            ProcCpu cpu = sigar.getProcCpu("Exe.Name.ct=eclipse.exe");
            System.out.println(cpu.getPercent());
        }
    } catch (SigarException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

this is a sample output I got

```
0.0
0.11450381679389313
0.12213740458015267
0.10714285714285714
0.0
0.0
0.0
```

some time some processes always consume zero percentage of CPU. therfore, Go to the task manager and find a process that  has a high CPU usage and give the exe of that process to the relevant place in code