# java detect window process with high CPU or memory usage

Tags: java, memory-management, cmd, window

how to detect window process with high CPU or memory usage
when detected the process is high CPU or memory usage, then restart it.
For example, when the "chrome.exe" is high CPU or memory usage and detected:
Then restart the chrome

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /im chrome.exe /f");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("start chrome");
```

Comment: Break the task down: 1) do you know how to get the task list (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/54686/how-to-get-a-list-of-current-open-windows-process-with-java) 2) do you know how to get the CPU or memory usage of a process in that list?

Comment: i know, tasklist is show all using process, but how can i detect the process which using a lot of CPU or memory usage? And i dont want to detect system process.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1767271/using-java-to-retrieve-the-cpu-usage-for-windows-processes

Comment: Possibly same as http://stackoverflow.com/q/33227718/4725592

Comment: @Rohan this idea is work for me!